# Using client certificates with wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk?

Tags: tpm, webkit

I'm running [wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk](https://snapcraft.io/wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk) in [ubuntu-frame](https://mir-server.io/ubuntu-frame) on Ubuntu 22.04.

I'd like to use a client certificate for accessing content on my server. I can't find any documentation on how to install a client certificate into wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk using a PCKS12 file or from the TPM using PCKS11. Is it possible to use client certificates in wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk?